# Why re.escape escapes space

Tags: python, regex

Recently, I just found `re.escape` is useful to get regular expression from a string quickly. When I pass a string like `'a b c'`, I'm confused that why every space is escaped with `\` character. AFAIK, writing an equivalent expression to match that string, it's unnecessary to escape the space character. Why does this difference happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does, because it is explicit. A space can literally match a space, but it can also be part of the regex in a verbose regular expression and not be meant for matching.

The resulting regex, i guess `/a\ b\ c/`, is a very explicit regex matching an a followed by a single space, followed by a b, followed by a single space, followed by a c.

If you write it yourself, you could also use `/a\sb\sc/` which would match any whitespace between the letters. Or even:

```
r = re.compile(r"""a #match a
b #match b
c #match c
"""
```

This last one would be compiled with [re.VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) and is a way to write your regex very fine readable in your sourcecode. This regex would ignore the spaces completly and therefore not match your case. With regex, always keep in mind, that everything that is not explicit, will fail some sunday morning at 3am.