# Why Python re.escape() escapes "#" character?

Tags: regex, python-re

Reading the `re.escape()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), it says

> Changed in version 3.3: The '_' character is no longer escaped.

> Changed in version 3.7: Only characters that can have special meaning in a regular expression are escaped. As a result, '!', '"', '%', "'", ',', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '@', and "`" are no longer escaped.

Question is, why `#` character is still escaped?

Comment: Because it is special when `re.X` flag is used.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419837/why-re-escape-escapes-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` option, the `#` char becomes special (as does any literal whitespace).

Check the code snippet below:

```py
import re
pattern = "# Something"
text = "Here is # Something"
print( re.search(pattern, text ) )
# => <re.Match object; span=(8, 19), match='# Something'>
print( re.search(pattern, text, re.X ) )
# => <re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6GyvBo).

When using `re.search(pattern, text, re.X )` there is no match because `# Something` is parsed as a comment, the `#` marks the single line comment start, all text after it till the line break is ignored in the pattern.

So, `re.escape` escapes `#`, then it is treated as a literal char when `re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` is used:

```py
print( re.search(re.escape(pattern), text, re.X ) )
# => <re.Match object; span=(8, 19), match='# Something'>
```